# const change without const_cast<> Why no compiler warning/error?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer

Code sample that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <functional>
#include <set>

void useCallback(std::function<void(char *)> callback)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(char const *)> callback = [](char const *)
    {
    };

    useCallback(callback);

    return 0;
}
```

Yes, the `const` removal is benign at the end of the day, `useCallback()` states in its API that it is prepared to accept and use a callback that modifies its parameter, so it'll do just fine with a function that doesn't.

Why then does the argument that prevents passing a `std::set<char *>` to a function that expects a `std::set<char const *>` not apply here?  That argument correctly points out that `char *` and `char const *` are different types, therefore the two sets are not type equivalent.

Keeping this in mind, why are the types of `callback` and the parameter to `useCallback()` not considered different?

-- Edit --

This is using MSVC, VS 2017.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: This is with MSVC.  I'd be curious to know what GCC thinks.

Comment: @dgnuff You can try it online on https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> That argument correctly points out that `char *` and `char const *` are different types, therefore the two sets are not type equivalent.

`std::function<void(char *)>` and `std::function<void(char const *)>` are different types too, therefore the two function objects are not type equivalent. It's just that unlike with `std::set`, they're not required to be type equivalent!

`std::function<void(char *)>` has a constructor which will accept any object that can be called with a `char *` argument. `std::function<void(char const *)>` can be called with a `char *` argument, so it is fine. It is this same constructor that's used when initialising a `std::function<T>` from a lambda: there too the types are different, but as long as the lambda can be invoked when passed the argument types in `T`, it is accepted.

Comment: And of course, if I take the parameter to `useCallback()` by reference, it **does** fail.

Comment: Will the `std::function<void(char *)>` store the full `std::function<void(char const *)>` as a target? When reading this up on cppreference, its seems like it will move the full `std::function` into the target of the destination `std::function`, and not just the target

Comment: Ah figured it out with the `target()` function. Indeed, the `std::function` objects are "stacked" and no conversion is applied ( like for example in the unique_ptr constuctor)

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem here. `const` is actually not being dropped here because calling `std::function<void(char const *)>` function with arguments suitable for `std::function<void(char *)>` (that is supplying `char *` parameter) is perfectly fine. The erroneous case would be the opposite situation:

```
void useCallback(std::function<void(char const *)> callback)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(char *)> callback = [](char *)
    {
    };

    useCallback(callback);

    return 0;
}
```

`std::function<void(char *)>` can not be invoked with the arguments suitable for `std::function<void(char const *)>` invocation. Therefore constructor of `std::function<void(char const *)>` function object should yield an error.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers nicely explain the reasons why this is perfectly legal and what the difference to `std::set` parameters is, I would like to contribute an example demonstrating that the type-safety isn't lost. Consider this

```
void useCallback(std::function<void(char *)> callback)
{
    callback("abc");
}
```

This will compile, though it converts a string literal to `const char*`, which gives you an appropriate warning with clang and gcc. This doesn't compile:

```
void useCallback(std::function<void(char *)> callback)
{
    const char *str = "abc";

    callback(str);
}
```

The original signature of `std::function<void(char const *)>` is hence still there and well maintained by the compiler.